# calc() function Error in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am using the examples at (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html#computed-variables) to generate a density plot. However, I have the below error:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
dsmall <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
d <- ggplot(dsmall, aes(x, y))
d + stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = calc(density)), contour = FALSE)

# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature    
# ‘"standardGeneric", "missing"’
```

Am I missing something? Is `density` some pre-computed object?

Could someone help?

Comment: `calc(x)` is the newer replacement for `..x..`, where `x` is a value computed by the `stat` function in use. However, `calc` is only in the github development version for now, not the CRAN version. So if you're not using the github version (2.2.1.9000), use `..x..`

Comment: And yes, `density` is computed by `stat_density_2d`

Comment: Great!!! it works by using ..density.., deceived by the doc pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
d + stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE)
```

And have a look to the documentation here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/geom_density_2d